# Existence of a statistical distance with a special property

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A, B, C, \ldots$ be a set of points. Is there a non-trivial or artificially cooked up statistical distance which satisfies the following conditions:

1. The nearest point to $A$ is $B$
2. Leaving aside $A$, the nearest point to $B$ is $C$
3. There exists a point $D \ne B$ such that the statistical distance between $A$ and $D$ is closer than that between $A$ and $C$

Comment: Are we working in the setting of a Euclidean space?

Comment: No, we are not in Euclidean space. In Euclidean space, it is trivial as in the attempted answer below.

Comment: Ok, so then it might be a good idea to tell us which space we are looking at.

Comment: This question appears to be problematic in two ways - (i) in spite of the insertion of the word 'statistical', it doesn't appear to have any statistical content - it simply appears to be asking about some kind of metric space;  and (ii) it doesn't appear to be a clear question (or rather, without some additional conditions it's trivial, so your question as written appears incomplete and hence unclear). Unless it's clearly a statistics question, it may be moved. Unless the question is clear, it may be put on hold.

Answer (score 3):

You could try $D=1, A=5, B=8, C=12$